# How to restrict certain API URL only mobile app (iOS/Android) are able to access

Tags: android, ios, web-services, api

I have integrated a bunch of third party libraries. This is just prevention, that I don't want any unwanted data sent out to any system (analytics,statistic) that I don't know of.

How to restrict API call from app to block other than my domain name, for example my app only connect to WS hosted in : www.testing.com and www.testAnalytcs.com. other than these 2 will throw invalid.